# SSR only rendering home page, but not the other pages

Tags: server-side-rendering, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I am having trouble with SSR and was wondering if someone can give me some tips as to where to look for fixing my issue. I have installed SSR, but whenever I refresh the page (regardless of the page I am on), the home page always gets returned from the server. Any suggestions?

Note: I haven't changed anything in the default server.ts file provided when installing SSR.

I am expecting the routes such as PDP to return the file generated from the server when opening or refreshing that page.

Answer (score 0):

Are the pages (on which you are trying to SSR) accessible without being logged in as a user/customer?
Spartacus/SAP only supports SSR for anonymous users. Using SSR in this case could have the effect of only serving the homepage/login page.